# div display if block jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying trying to find out if a div style display is block then do something
here is an e.g

this is just a guess i am tryng to do it in jquery

```
 if("#toshow":"display" == "block"){

 }else{

 }
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

So you want to distinguish between `display: block` and `display: none` ? If so, you can better use the [`is()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Is) function in combination with the [`:visible`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) selector for this:

```
if ($('#toshow').is(':visible')) {

} else {

}
```

This works regardless of if you used `display: block`, or `display: inline`, or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @Dustin: I'm not sure why you're posting a comment like that while this is very simple to experiment yourself. If you're having a problem with this specific case, it's caused elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, let's put it this way. This will work if you want to know if the div is currently visible. This won't work if you want to know if the div is a block (the original question, which also led me to this stackoverflow question from a Google search.) In my case, I wanted to know if a (currently hidden) div was going to be hidden when I revealed the parent div. http://jsfiddle.net/ejVvu/1/ as you can see, this answer won't work to check if a div has a block attribute (the original question.) So, +1 for a "better" solution for current visibility, but not the answer to the question.

Comment: @Dustin: the answer just answered what the OP **actually** needed. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Your point is valid, I'm not sure what the right approach is here since the way the OP worded his question, was *exactly* what I needed to know, which Brian answered. Yet, with the XY problem philosophy, and the fact that the OP's div ID was #toshow, you may be correct to infer that he actually needed a way to determine if something was visible in the moment. Perhaps a request to clarify the question, or an expanded answer to include a direct answer and a "what you might actually need is..." alternative. Anyways, hopefully my fiddle will help users that were in my situation. TY for the XY link

Answer (score 16):

You need to use the [`css`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#name) function.

```
if($("#toshow").css("display") == "block"){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#toshow').css('display') == 'block') {
        // Do something.
    } else {
        // Do something else.
    }
});
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget your `:visible` selector.

```
if ($("#toshow:visible").length) {
  // it's visible
} else {
  // it's not visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This option worked perfectly. I am Brazilian and I had to translate the text, but when I saw the code I immediately saw that it was the correct option.

```js
function reversoObjeto() {
  $('#janela').fadeToggle(500, function(e) {
    if ($("#janela").css("display") == "none") {
      alert("Janela Apagou!");
    } else {
      alert("Janela Acendeu!");
    }
  })
}
```