# Disabling the scrollbar with active menu overlay

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having trouble with disabling the scroll bar on my website when the menu overlay is active (class: .overlay). I created a menu overlay and I would like the scroll bar to be disabled when the overlay is visible. Similar to this [Just disable scroll not hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So I would like to *disable* the scroll bar, not *hide* it.
What I understand so far: Basically what I need to do is to add inline CSS to the html when the overlay is on display: block and remove the inline CSS when the overlay is on display: none;

I tried multiple solutions given on Stackoverflow, but no result so far. This was my latest solution, which didnt work in the end:

```
if( $(".overlay").css('display') == 'block') { 

$('html').css('position','fixed');
$('html').css('overflow-y','scroll');
$('html').css('width','100%');

} else {
$('html').css('position','');
$('html').css('overflow-y','');
$('html').css('width','');
}
```

Above is based on this: [div display if block jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083147/div-display-if-block-jquery)

Here is my website (under development):

http://www.wouterpasman.com/view/

The menu overlay is activated when you click the menu button in the top right corner. Goal: When the overlay is active, the scroll bar should be temporarily disabled, but still visible.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an overflow hidden and auto :

```
if( $(".overlay").css('display') == 'block') { 
   $('html').css('position','fixed');
   $('html').css('overflow-y','hidden');
   $('html').css('width','100%');
} else {
   $('html').css('position','');
   $('html').css('overflow-y','');
   $('html').css('width','');
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this code doesn't work properly (similar to my code) or at least there is nothing added to the HTML once the overlay menu is display:block. It seems this part if( $(".overlay").css('display') == 'block') { has no effect ...

Comment: Also isn't overflow:hidden hiding the scrollbar instead of just disabling it? I would like to disable the scroll bar, not hide it.

Comment: for your test, try : $('.overlay').is(':visible') instead of $('.overlay').css('display') == 'block', and for your scroll, you just need to disable the event temporarly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily